# Third Exception not executing Python try/except

Tags: python, exception

Code of my function, basically it runs thru multiple links and checks for various buttons until it finds the right one.. try A, except nosuch B except nosuch C... the issue is after the second one it doesnt recognize that there is a 3rd except NoSuchElement. Did I format it wrong or something?

```
def followerviewer():

    user_str = " "
    followaction = 0


    for acc_len in range(len(acc_list)):
        user_str = f"{acc_list[acc_len]}"
        driver.get(f"https://instagram.com/{user_str}/")
        try:
            followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Requested"]')
            followaction = 0
        except NoSuchElementException:

            followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Message"]')
            followaction = 0

        except NoSuchElementException:
            followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
            followaction = 1



        if bool(followaction) is True:
            followbutton.click()
        else:
            print("Is already followed")

        time.sleep(0.25)




    return
```

My third exception is not working, I'm getting this error..

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()="Message"]"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)

I thought it was a syntax issue but I checked how to handle Exceptions online and its weird why it isnt working..

Comment: your first ```NoSuchElementException``` exception catches all "NoSuchElementExceptions".  So your second exception won't run.  You need to determine in the first exception which of the exception applies (either the  "Message" one or the "Follow" one.

Comment: @ewong `followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Message"]')` can throw an exception again.

Comment: Were you expecting the second `except` block to catch exceptions from the first? `except` blocks don't chain like that. Multiple `except`s on the same `try` are for catching different kinds of exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting a try in the except. I'm assuming here that the third except runs on the previous one failing. So try this code:

```
def followerviewer():
 user_str = " "
 followaction = 0


 for acc_len in range(len(acc_list)):
    user_str = f"{acc_list[acc_len]}"
    driver.get(f"https://instagram.com/{user_str}/")
    try:
        followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Requested"]')
        followaction = 0
    except NoSuchElementException:
       try
           followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Message"]')
           followaction = 0

       except NoSuchElementException:

           followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
           followaction = 1



    if bool(followaction) is True:
        followbutton.click()
    else:
        print("Is already followed")

    time.sleep(0.25)




 return
```

Comment: thanks, I tried try: except: try: except, but this didnt come across, ty!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is nested try/catch block:

```
    try:
        followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Requested"]')
        followaction = 0
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Message"]')
            followaction = 0
        except NoSuchElementException:
            followbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
            followaction = 1
```

That way it can catch `NoSuchElementException` when you run `find_element_by_xpath` again